# Problem with gpg when using apt

Tags: debian, apt, gpg, node.js

I'm scratching my head to find a way to correct broken gpg stuff in `apt`.

When i try to install Nodejs :

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_7.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

I get this error :

```
## You seem to be using Debian version stretch.
## This maps to Debian "jessie"... Adjusting for you...

## Confirming "jessie" is supported...

+ curl -sLf -o /dev/null 'https://deb.nodesource.com/node_7.x/dists/jessie/Release'

## Adding the NodeSource signing key to your keyring...

+ curl -s https://deb.nodesource.com/gpgkey/nodesource.gpg.key | apt-key add -
gpg: [don't know]: invalid packet (ctb=00)
gpg: keydb_get_keyblock failed: Valeur non trouvée
gpg: [don't know]: invalid packet (ctb=00)
gpg: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.ix2LFsfXOw/pubring.gpg: copy to '/tmp/apt-key-gpghome.ix2LFsfXOw/pubring.gpg.tmp' failed: Paquet incorrect
gpg: error writing keyring '/tmp/apt-key-gpghome.ix2LFsfXOw/pubring.gpg': Paquet incorrect
gpg: [don't know]: invalid packet (ctb=00)
gpg: error reading '-': Paquet incorrect
gpg: import from '-' failed: Paquet incorrect
Error executing command, exiting
```

I use a Debian stretch rc2 with kernel 10.5. Don't know if it's the problem or not. I can't use stable version of debian because i'm running on a Ryzen processor.

When i try to install VSCode, i got another error too:

```
W: Erreur de GPG : http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease : Les signatures suivantes n'ont pas pu être vérifiées car la clé publique n'est pas disponible : NO_PUBKEY EB3E94ADBE1229CF
W: The repository 'http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease' is not signed.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Any idea?

[EDIT]
This is my source.list

```
deb http://ftp.univ-pau.fr/linux/mirrors/debian/ stretch main non-free contrib 
deb-src http://ftp.univ-pau.fr/linux/mirrors/debian/ stretch main non-free contrib 

deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security/ stretch/updates main contrib non-free 
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security/ stretch/updates main contrib non-free 

# stretch-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://ftp.univ-pau.fr/linux/mirrors/debian/ stretch-updates main contrib non-free 
deb-src http://ftp.univ-pau.fr/linux/mirrors/debian/ stretch-updates main contrib non-free 

# stretch-backports, previously on backports.debian.org
deb http://ftp.univ-pau.fr/linux/mirrors/debian/ stretch-backports main contrib non-free 
deb-src http://ftp.univ-pau.fr/linux/mirrors/debian/ stretch-backports main contrib non-free 

# deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/ stretch stable 
# deb-src [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/ stretch stable 
deb http://www.deb-multimedia.org/ stretch main non-free 
deb [arch=amd64] http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable main
```

Comment: Welcome to U&L , please add the content of your `/etc/apt/sources.list`[here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/356735/edit)

Comment: `curl | sudo bash` is always a bad idea! You're executed stuff as root on your box without any knowledge of what it does.

Answer (score 0):

I understand this is an old question, and may be Overcome By Events (OBE)... However...

It seems there are a few problems that coincidentally occurred simultaneously.

**Problem 1:** *Nodejs repo GPG public keys*

I didn't have any problem downloading the keys, so perhaps the repo was having connectivity problems or some other glitch that particular day.

Here's my test of reading the repo public keys:

```
$ curl -s https://deb.nodesource.com/gpgkey/nodesource.gpg.key |gpg --list-packets

# off=0 ctb=99 tag=6 hlen=3 plen=525
:public key packet:
    version 4, algo 1, created 1402676406, expires 0
    pkey[0]: [4096 bits]
    pkey[1]: [17 bits]
    keyid: 1655A0AB68576280
# off=528 ctb=b4 tag=13 hlen=2 plen=31
:user ID packet: "NodeSource <gpg@nodesource.com>"
# off=561 ctb=89 tag=2 hlen=3 plen=568
:signature packet: algo 1, keyid 1655A0AB68576280
    version 4, created 1402676406, md5len 0, sigclass 0x13
    digest algo 2, begin of digest 74 e6
    hashed subpkt 2 len 4 (sig created 2014-06-13)
    hashed subpkt 27 len 1 (key flags: 03)
    hashed subpkt 11 len 5 (pref-sym-algos: 9 8 7 3 2)
    hashed subpkt 21 len 5 (pref-hash-algos: 8 2 9 10 11)
    hashed subpkt 22 len 3 (pref-zip-algos: 2 3 1)
    hashed subpkt 30 len 1 (features: 01)
    hashed subpkt 23 len 1 (keyserver preferences: 80)
    subpkt 16 len 8 (issuer key ID 1655A0AB68576280)
    data: [4095 bits]
# off=1132 ctb=b9 tag=14 hlen=3 plen=525
:public sub key packet:
    version 4, algo 1, created 1402676406, expires 0
    pkey[0]: [4096 bits]
    pkey[1]: [17 bits]
    keyid: 6C5CDECAAA01DA2C
# off=1660 ctb=89 tag=2 hlen=3 plen=543
:signature packet: algo 1, keyid 1655A0AB68576280
    version 4, created 1402676406, md5len 0, sigclass 0x18
    digest algo 2, begin of digest 83 d0
    hashed subpkt 2 len 4 (sig created 2014-06-13)
    hashed subpkt 27 len 1 (key flags: 0C)
    subpkt 16 len 8 (issuer key ID 1655A0AB68576280)
    data: [4096 bits]
```

**Problem 2:** *Microsoft repo GPG public keys*

The problem here is that the Microsoft public keys are located in a separate directory on the Microsoft repo server.

I found the key file at:

https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc

Here's my test of reading Microsoft's repo public keys:

```
$ curl -s https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc |gpg --list-packets
# off=0 ctb=99 tag=6 hlen=3 plen=269
:public key packet:
    version 4, algo 1, created 1446074508, expires 0
    pkey[0]: [2048 bits]
    pkey[1]: [17 bits]
    keyid: EB3E94ADBE1229CF
# off=272 ctb=b4 tag=13 hlen=2 plen=55
:user ID packet: "Microsoft (Release signing) <gpgsecurity@microsoft.com>"
# off=329 ctb=89 tag=2 hlen=3 plen=309
:signature packet: algo 1, keyid EB3E94ADBE1229CF
    version 4, created 1446074508, md5len 0, sigclass 0x13
    digest algo 2, begin of digest 1a 9b
    hashed subpkt 2 len 4 (sig created 2015-10-28)
    hashed subpkt 27 len 1 (key flags: 03)
    hashed subpkt 11 len 5 (pref-sym-algos: 9 8 7 3 2)
    hashed subpkt 21 len 3 (pref-hash-algos: 2 8 3)
    hashed subpkt 22 len 2 (pref-zip-algos: 2 1)
    hashed subpkt 30 len 1 (features: 01)
    hashed subpkt 23 len 1 (keyserver preferences: 80)
    subpkt 16 len 8 (issuer key ID EB3E94ADBE1229CF)
    data: [2047 bits]
```

**Problem 3:** *Missing forward slash in repo URL*

There is a missing forward slash in your `/etc/apt/sources.list` line for Microsoft's repo.

This line:

`deb [arch=amd64] http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable main`

Should be:

`deb [arch=amd64] http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode/ stable main`

**Complete solution**

1. Re-try installing `nodejs`
2. Add the missing forward slash in `/etc/apt/sources.list`
3. Download and add Microsoft's repo signing keys:

`curl -s https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc |apt-key add -`

Comment: [`apt-key` is now deprecated](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/717434/apt-key-is-deprecated-what-do-i-do-instead-of-add-apt-repository)