# GPG error when I want to apt update

Tags: apt, kali-linux, repository, gpg, openpgp

I just installed Kali NetHunter and I'm trying to do a simple `apt update` but it looks like a public key is missing

```
root@kali:~# apt-get update
 0% [Waiting for headers] [Connected to packages.microsoft.com (13.8Get:2 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/microsoft-debian-stretch-prod stretch InRelease [3232 B]
 Hit:1 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling InRelease
 Err:2 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/microsoft-debian-stretch-prod stretch InRelease
   The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY EB3E94ADBE1229CF
 Reading package lists... Done
 W: GPG error: https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/microsoft-debian-stretch-prod stretch InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY EB3E94ADBE1229CF
 E: The repository 'https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/microsoft-debian-stretch-prod stretch InRelease' is not signed.
 N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
 N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I tried

```
curl -s https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/microsoft-debian-stretch-prod/dists/stretch/Release.gpg | apt-key add -
```

and

```
wget --no-check-certificate https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/microsoft-debian-stretch-prod/dists/stretch/Release.gpg | apt-key add -
```

And the result was `gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found` for both

Comment: Has Kali changed their policy regarding 3rd-party repositories? Last I knew, they only wanted kali.org in the sources.list...

Comment: Same pubkey error: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/479137/117549

Comment: There's nothing else than the kali repo in the `sources.list` but I found a `microsoft.list`  inside `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` 
And I don't think it's the same problem since even `curl -s https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc |apt-key add -` give me the same result `gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found`

Comment: @JeffSchaller You [are correct](https://docs.kali.org/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories): "Any additional repositories added to the Kali sources.list file will most likely BREAK YOUR KALI LINUX INSTALL."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workaround solution I found is to delete `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft.list` and to make sure the kali repo is uncommented and is inside the main `/etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: to solve a problem remove it???  not really
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | sudo apt-key add -

Answer (score 3):

load the key from microsoft

```
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | sudo apt-key add -
```

Comment: This was the first thing I tried after encountering an error when installing the mono-project repo in Ubuntu 20.10, and apparently it was all that was necessary. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. `cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d`
2. `ls` (showed microsoft.sources.list.d)
3. `cd`
4. `rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft.sources.list.d`

Now it has removed the message when trying to update; however, I don't know if I have done this correctly as I am new to this.

Answer (score 0):

For raspberrypi is kind of the same, it was just commented the source file and then executed `apt update` again.

```
# cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list
### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
# deb [arch=amd64,arm64,armhf] http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable main
```