# apt-key is deprecated. What do I do instead of add-apt-repository

Tags: apt

`apt-key` is deprecated, as indicated by it's man page.

`add-apt-repository` uses apt-key in the background. As of Ubuntu 22.04, this will issue a warning message when used, and then on every apt update.

When instructed to use `add-apt-repository` (like installing [lutris](https://lutris.net/downloads)), what should I do instead in order to avoid the use of apt-key?

Note: Previously added repository keys can be fixed, with solution like [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1407632/key-is-stored-in-legacy-trusted-gpg-keyring-etc-apt-trusted-gpg). I'm asking here for a solution that does not require to first use a deprecated tool then fix what this tool has done.

Comment: Those links don't indicate that `apt-key` is deprecated. They indicate that your keys are stored in a deprecated *format*, and provide instructions for upgrading the storage format. See also https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-fix-the-apt-key-deprecated-warning-in-ubuntu/.

Comment: `man apt-key` indicates "Deprecated APT key management utility". Using `add-apt-repository` will issue `Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).`. The link you provide fix previously added repositories. I want a tool that will not require a fix and won't use deprecated tools

Comment: Fair enough! I didn't see any deprecation errors or key related problems while working with add-apt-repository and apt-key on an ubuntu 20.04 system, but I'm not going to argue with the documentation! Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: The warning message appeared when I upgraded to Mint 21, so that would be equivalent to Ubuntu 22.04. Previous version probably did not issue warning or implement the deprecation

Answer (score 1):

Digital Ocean [recommends](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-handle-apt-key-and-add-apt-repository-deprecation-using-gpg-to-add-external-repositories-on-ubuntu-22-04#addendum-adding-an-external-repository-using-a-keyserver) using `gpg` as an alternative to `add-apt-repository`.

The following is an example of how `gpg` can be used to install the `R` language, you will just need to adapt the commands for the repository that you are interested in adding:

```bash
# Download the key from the keyserver
sudo gpg --homedir /tmp --no-default-keyring --keyring /usr/share/keyrings/R.gpg \
  --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9

# Add the repository to a `.list` file
echo "deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/R.gpg] https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu jammy-cran40/" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/R.list > /dev/null

# Update your repository list
sudo apt update

# Install the package
sudo apt install r-base
```

The explanation for the flags to the `gpg` commands are as follows, courtesy of the Digital Ocean article:

- `--no-default-keyring` combined with `--keyring` allows outputting to a new file instead of importing into an existing keyring, which is the default behavior of `gpg` in this scenario.
- `--keyserver` combined with `--recv-keys` provides the specific key and location you’re downloading from.
- `--homedir` is used to overwrite the `gpg` default location for creating temporary files. `gpg` needs to create these files to complete the command, otherwise `gpg` will attempt to write to `/root` which causes a permission error. Instead, this command places the temporary files in the appropriate `/tmp` directory.

Comment: How do I find the keyserver adress and key? (in the example "E298A3..."), given just the name of the repo or ppa?

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Linux Mint, there is an **easy and correct solution** (for the time being):
**(For Ubuntu, see below.)**

**There is a version available that works fine**, but it’s somehow not in the repositories for literal *months* now. (I would be ashamed, if I were the maintainer.)
You can install it manually though:

- Grab the latest `mintsources_*.zip` from **https://github.com/linuxmint/mintsources/issues/240**
- Unzip to a temporary dir.
- Open all the `.deb` files in there, and click on “Install”.
- Remove the temporary dir again.
- Don’t forget to make sure if the package ever ends up in the official repositories, that newer versions that what you have installed are actually picked up. (E.g. Set a reminder to come here again in a couple of months, and find if there are newer versions than what you have installed.)

I just tried it, and it correctly puts the files in `/etc/apt/keyrings` and uses the correct `deb [arch=… signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/….gpg] …` syntax in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list`.

**Maybe it works in plain Ubuntu too.** CLI `apt-key` and `apt-add-repository` should work at least, even if `mintsources` (the GUI tool) clearly is made for Mint. If the `.deb` are a hassle, maybe unpacking stuff from `mintsources_2.1.11.tar.xz:/usr/` to you `/usr/local/` (!!) should get it to work (provided the dependencies are there).

I hope this finally solves this miserable situation.

Comment: @muru: Hey, yeah, I see it. I had a bad connection, which seems to have caused a case of the two generals problem. (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IP-rGJKSZ3s)

Comment: @terdon: Thanks for deleting the duplicate.